# UseState hook setter never doing anything

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on an application I've contributing to for a while, and for some reason a new hook setter that I wrote won't update even if I call the setter with a dummy value.

Here's the setup:

```
const [symbols, setSymbols] = useState([]);

//... more application code between ...

if (symbols_cache != undefined) {

  let cache = JSON.parse(symbols_cache);

  // setSymbols(cache);
  setSymbols([1,2,3]);

  console.log("cache is", cache);
  console.log("symbols is, after cache set:", symbols);
}

//... more application code between ...


useEffect(() => {
  console.log("symbols in symbols hook", symbols);
  if (symbols.length == 0) return;

}, [symbols]);
```

This outputs:

```
cache is Array(283) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
symbols is, after cache set: Array []
symbols in symbols hook: Array []
```

I'm pretty stumped. Let me know if there's enough information here to answer the question, otherwise, I can add more.

Comment: If you are trying to initialize symbols with the cache, try `... useState(symbols_cache  == null ? [] : JSON.parse(symbols_cache))`. Also, your `useEffect` is doing nothing.

Comment: Read up about state. State doesn't change until re-render. Calling `setState(1)` is not the same as saying `state = 1`. What you're doing is queueing an update, but the update doesn't happen until your function finishes running, so you're always gonna see the same value that you started with.